# Google Scripts user ID who clicks on button

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have created a button on the google sheet, I am sharing the sheet with multiple users. Is there any way to get the id of the specific user who has clicked the button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [Class Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session) wherein you can use the `getActiveUser()` method.

With this method, you can get information about the current user. If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, `User.getEmail()` returns a blank string.

Hope that helps!